# unwanted sharp edges on shade smooth object

Tags: rendering, edges, bevel, smooth

I have imported some CAD object. It is made of triangles and the edges have some sort of bevel:

[image: object wireframe]

I want to smooth it out. When I use Shade Smooth, it works fine, except for those bevelled edges which appears flat (sharp corners instead of rounded ring around the object) in the render/material preview. Except that, everything seems to be smooth:

[image]

I have played around with an Auto Smooth, Edge split modifier and SubSurf modifier. Nothing helps and it even make it worse with weird shading.

Is there any solution to this except for remodelling the object or its parts?

Comment: A subsurface modifier should work. Did you use the Catmull-Clark or the Simple algorithm? Only Catmull-Clark smoothes out the geometry.

Comment: @Joachim Yes, I used Catmul-Clark. Now I have tried Tris -> Quads and then SubSurf modifier and it helped a lot (only level 1 however, as with 2 or more causes a a little bit of wierd shading again). Normals are fine by the way